# Can spark execute table operations on remote nodes? (vs. row operations)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Most of spark's Dataset functions are per-row operations. However, I'd like to distribute execution of ML tasks to run on Spark -- most ML tasks are naturally operations that are functions of tables, and not natually functions of rows. (I've looked at MLLib -- its way too limited, and in many cases execution is made orders of magnitude slower in spark by distribute operations over many cores that could otherwise fit on a single core).

Its important that ML algorithms process collections of rows, not single rows, and so I'd like to materialize a table into memory on a node. (I pinky promise it will fit into core). How can I do this?

Functionally, I'd like to do:

```
def mlsubtask(table, arg2, arg3):
     data = table.collect()
     ...

sc = SparkContext(...)
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
...
df = sqlctx.sql("SELECT ...")
results = sc.parallelize([(df,arg2,arg3),(df,arg2,arg3),(df,arg2,arg3)]).map(mlsubtask).collect()
```

If *can* perform execution like this:

```
sc = SparkContext(...)
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
...
df = sqlctx.sql("SELECT ...")
df = df.collect()
results = sc.parallelize([(df,arg2,arg3),(df,arg2,arg3),(df,arg2,arg3)]).map(mlsubtask).collect()
```

... but this brings the data to the client, which in then re-serialized and quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

For a single task:

```
def mlsubtask(iter_rows):
    data_table = list(iter_rows) # Or other way of bringing into memory.
   ...

df.repartition(1).mapPartitions(mlsubtask)
```